# Are these 2 circuits interchangeble?

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio

I found the upper circuit. Originally it is designed as an output circuit for an audio player with a jack output. I have no transistora lying around, but opamps like the TL074.

I made the lower design.
On the right you see the in (green) and outputs of the circuits.

My questions,

1. Is the design at the bottom a good substitution for the top circuit?
2. Is R4 is for impedance matching? (Then I probably should add it.)

[image]

Comment: The op-amp needs biasing because it is single-supplied. Probably, R4 is a protecting resistor. Impedance matching is something different. It requires to make the load impedance (if possible) equal to the output impedance but not the opposite. Adding a resistor in series to the amp output only decreases the voltage.

Answer (score 0):

The op-amp needs biasing because it is single-supplied.

Regarding R4, probably it is a protecting resistor. Impedance matching is something different. It requires to make the load impedance (if possible) equal to the output impedance but not the opposite. Adding a resistor in series to the amp output only decreases the voltage.

Comment: Also note that impedance matching is largely unnecessary for anything even close to audio frequencies, at least when using semiconductors and not vacuum tubes.

Comment: I am not familiar with the details of this problem but I have a good intuitive idea of ​​it (in general). I must admit that I do not understand very well your practical considerations...

Comment: How about this: I add a negative power supply of -12v to the opamp, would that solve the biasing issue? (It was my assumption that the cap removes the dc component from the input signal (which had a 6V DC offset), so no need for a negative power supply.)

Comment: Yes, you are right about the DC component... I have not seen it... Actually, it serves as a biasing ("lifting") voltage in both circuits. C2 removes the DC component from the output signal ("shifts" it down).

Comment: Ok, the general idea: The source signal has a 6VDC offset (with a signal swing of 6V p-p), goes through a voltage follower and the C2 cap removes the DC and goes to the jack out part. Simple enough: In my understanding: no negative powersupply needed (but ifso, it is available though).

Comment: Well written... Agree!

Answer (score 0):

> *Is the design at the bottom a good substitution for the top circuit?*

They are only interchangeable if their \$\color{red}{\text{intended function is known}}\$. The intended function is what the circuit is meant to accomplish in the wider sense i.e. what they connect to and what range of input signals they are expected to buffer without creating distortion.

Given that the NPN circuit can swing it's output down to nearly 0 volts but the [TL074](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slos080n/slos080n.pdf?ts=1597583722582&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) is limited to only swinging its output down to 3 volts above its negative rail (0 volts in your circuit) then it's unlikely that they are compatible in the wider sense. Try increasing the sinewave amplitude to see what I mean.

Also, the TL074 will be significantly limited on bandwidth compared to virtually all NPN transistors, it makes it difficult to say that they are compatible.

[image]

The above areas highlighted in red are potential problem areas.

> *Is R4 is for impedance matching?*

Impossible to say given the details you have provided. For instance, to the right of C2 might be a capacitor down to ground and then R4 would probably be regarded as forming a low pass filter with that "invisible" capacitor. In other words, we don't know the provenance of your circuitry.

Comment: The asker says that it's an output driver for an audio amplifier, so I'd assume R4 is not for impedance matching if it's only working at audio frequencies. It may be filtering, though.

Comment: @Hearth you are quite right but my point is that without more details, it would be foolish to agree - that's why I cited the example of a filter.

Answer (score 0):

With DC bias to NPN added output impedance is basically Re so a series R4 is only to prevent capacitive  load parasitics oscillations so it can be small such as >Rbe. Yet OA with high gain has an output impedance of ~200 Ohms/ open loop gain so essentially 0 ohms until current limited by design.

Whereas for large signal out Load is critical for emitter follower and AC couple loads must be >Re to prevent starving emitter current which raises output impedance instantly.

But for high impedance loads you want to consider CR=Tau relaxation charge time constant on startups on output or rise time=0.35/f-3dB for 10~90% not asymptotic voltage at 0 to 64% Vdc as a square wave becomes triangular near cutoff f.

For a preamp you would use Re to be less than load and series R to any smaller R>rBE junction resistance for stability reasons from current feedback to base from reactance Cout load of cable capacitance like a phono coax cable.  Yet to drive a speaker you want complementary emitter follower Darlington power transistors even with Op Amp inside the feedback loop to boost current. Often you see 25kHz RC snubber 4Ohm load to 0V to prevent same parasitic emitter-follower power driver oscillations.  Remember stability criteria is Av<1 for positive feedback, so an emitter follower with Av~<1 depending  on loading needs some reactive resonant cable load gain of >Av to make it oscillate at that frequency for an emitter follower. That’s the only reason why you might see a series R on output AC coupled in audio preamps, then prefer shunt Royer snubber on power amps.